# C++ Random Number Check for Very Small Probabilities

Tags: c++, random, probability

I have a very small probability of an event occurring (of order 1e-5) and am trying to use a uniform random number to test for success. As the probability drops to around 1e-4 the fraction of successes no longer matches the probability in the test code below.

How can I get an accurate check for success with such small probabilities? I tried using other random number generators but all the suggestions I found were for C++11 which I am not using. Many thanks in advance!

```
#include <cstlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double Prob, rand_num, frac_success;
int num_success, num_tries;

Prob = 1e-4;
num_tries = 1e8;
num_success = 0;

for (int i=0; i<num_tries; i++) {
    rand_num = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;    // random number between 0 and 1

    if (rand_num < Prob) {
        num_success ++;              // Record success
    }
}
frac_success = double(num_success) / double(num_tries);

cout << Prob << endl << frac_success << endl;
```

The fraction of successes is roughly equal to Prob when Prob = 1e-3, but for Prob = 1e-4 it is always greater than 1.2e-4. The discrepancy gets worse with lower probabilities, and does not seem to be fixed by increasing the number of tries.

EDIT:

As said by DiJuMx and Stefano Sanfilippo it seems rand() simply isn't a good enough generator to use. I decided to change to C++11 so I could use the uniform_real_distribution which solves the problem (this meant changes to other non-C++11 code but there was happily less to change than I expected).

Comment: *Why* are you not using the [C++11 pseudo-random number functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)?

Comment: What platform are you using? In particular, what is `RAND_MAX`?

Comment: Are you calling `srand()` at some point?

Comment: With g++ 4.8, `frac_success` is accurate even for `Prob = 1e-6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand()` is a very bad RNG, it would be ok just for implementing tic-tac-toe, but not for any serious business.

If you can't use C+11 `random` module, you can still take advantage of [`Boost.Random`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_random.html), which works with C++03 too. Browse the [generators page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators) and look for the best suit.

Comment: Is this the cause of the OP's problem?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth since the OP wrote _"How can I get an accurate check for success with such small probabilities?"_, I guess the issue is that the skewness of `rand()` becomes relevant when testing such a small value (`1e-4`), yielding to biased results. OP needs a good uniform distribution of random values.

Comment: There are many cases (testing for example) where the quality of random numbers doesn't really matter, so it can be used for "serious business". You only have to make sure that you get the required number of bits, possibly by calling `rand` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like your value of `RAND_MAX` is too small.

Consider the fact that `rand()` returns an integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX`. If you divide this number by `RAND_MAX` then, besides `0`, the smallest number you can get is `1.0/RAND_MAX`.

When `RAND_MAX` is `32767`, the smallest value is `3e-5`. Whereas, on my machine, `RAND_MAX` is `2147483647`, so the smallest value is `4e-10`.

Alternatively, look at Stefano's answer about using C++ specific libraries.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to consider that your estimator comes with a certain error. I didnt find a good link, in short it is:

```
H = success / trials      // your estimator
E(H) = p                  // the expectation value is the real probability 
Var(H) = p(1-p)/n         // variance of your estimator
```

This alone would suggest that you should get better results for smaller probabilities.

However, as suggested in the other answers, you should use a proper random number generator.

The rng should produces each possible outcome with same probablity (if its uniform). Lets say for a moment `RAND_MAX=3`. If we run it often enough, each possible value will occur with the same frequency and we get the same result as if we used each value only once. Now consider

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){std::cout << (double)i/3 << std::endl;}
```

this will produce

```
0
0.333333
0.666667
1
```

This will give reasonable results for not too small probabilities (eg. when trying to find `p=0.5` by chance you can find the exact value). However, when you try to find a small probability, the result will be too big.

The effect is the same when `RAND_MAX=32767`, it just shows up for smaller probabilities (somewhere around `p < 1/RAND_MAX`). Actually I dont know if this can be fixed by simply dividing by `RAND_MAX+1` but [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) is a video that quite nicely dramatizes and explains the problems with rand().

Answer (score -1):

If you suspect your random number generator has a bias you can check it by running it a large number of times and generating the frequency distribution.

Try it with different seeds and see if the bias holds.

If it does have a steady bias, record the distribution and use this to overcome the bias.